# Website fails to connect to SQL server with Error - 26 server not found

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am developing one website but when I add database in my website that time give error like that:

A network related or specific error occur when establishing a connection to SQL server. The servser was not found or not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and is Sql server configured to allow remote connection. (provider: SQL network interface, error 26-error locating Server/Instance Specified)

Please help me for this problem.

Comment: Have you actually made any effort to solve this yourself? You can't just expect to post an error message and ask us to "fix it".

Comment: How did you add a database to your website?  You've given very little explanation of what you've actually done.

Comment: Have you started all required database server from Server Management Console?? If not please verify it, also verify your connection string values for validity.

Comment: right click in my website folder and click new item then select sqldatabase that time give me error-26

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources on the Web for debugging this error.
Here's one: http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2011/05/sql-server-error-26-troubleshooting-checklist.html